# Angular Js is removing Sub-Directory from URL

Tags: angularjs, joomla, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have installed my Angular App in a location like this:
`http://example.com/my-app`

My App routing is like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {  

    $routeProvider
        .when('/templates', {
            controller: 'TemplatesController',          
            templateUrl: '/components/com_myApp/myApp/views/templates/template-list.html'
        })  

        .when('/apps', {
            controller: 'AppController',            
            templateUrl: '/components/com_myApp/myApp/views/apps/app-list.html'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/templates'    
        }); 

}]);
```

Now what happens is, when I go to `http://example.com/my-app`, the url instead of showing `http://example.com/my-app#/templates` it is showing as `http://example.com/templates`

It seems the `otherwise` condition is basically removing the base directory `my-app#` from the url. I have been scratching my head over this and after reading I also tried adding base url to head tag and tried changing the `myApp.config` to this:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
....
}
```

But although the routing seems to work when using `$locationProvider` like the above, the base url is still not showing the way I want it. The url is showing like this `http://example.com/templates` without `my-app` in the url path. I dont want Angular to remove the base path from the URL and I want the urls to show like this `http://example.com/my-app/..xyz...`

Why is Angular doing this?

Comment: Hey have you used  <base href="/my-app/" /> i mean both side backslash in base tag ..??

Comment: My base url is created automatically by Joomla like this `<base href="http://example.com/my-app" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you've instructed Angular to not use hashbang URLs by specifying `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. Remove or otherwise comment out that code snippet and if you specified `<base href="/">` in your root template file, remove or comment out that also and just use `ngRoute` without those.

Comment: #Rookie I tried Commenting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and `base href`but it doesnt help. Also my first sample above does not use `locationProvider` and that has the same problem too. Routing works when I visit angular pages like `#/templates` but when I visit the default page `http://example.com/my-app`, instead of the url showing `http://example.com/my-app/#templates/` it shows `http://example.com/templates`. This is the case in both examples I've shown above (with and without `$locationProvider`). My base url is created automatically by Joomla like this `http://example.com/my-app`

Comment: Also adding to that, when I go to `http://example.com/my-app`, the url in the browser shows this for like half a second `http://example.com/my-app#/templates` and then it immediately changes to `http://example.com/templates`. The view is showing the `template-list.html` page correctly but the url for some reason shows the correct one first and then changes quickly to `http://example.com/templates`. That is strange.

Comment: Okay. It appears the problem isn't with Angular but rather how your Joomla backend is serving the template that handles your root url -- `/my-app`. I don't have any experience with Joomla but in general, the backend serves that index template as a static HTML file containing all your JS scripts (including Angular) in `<script>` tags and those JS files are what will enable Angular take over the routing from the backend (i.e the routing is handled entirely client-side). Hopefully that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Makes sense @Rookie. I will dig deeper from the Joomla end and see why this odd behaviour, I added this Angular js as a Joomla component and created a menu item for it. What you say does make sense. I will update back if I was able to identify the issue (hopefully by tomorrow). Thanks again for reading my question and writing to me after looking at my Angular settings. I appreciate that :)